# Protect Google Maps API key with Restriction for Ionic app

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-api

[image: Google API Key]

I am working on ionic app and I want to redirect user from app to google map application for showing directions to user but when I am setting a `Key restriction` to `NONE` it works perfectly.

But when I set restriction to `Android apps` and provide a proper Package name & SHA-1 It give me error: `Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError`.

I think it is because:

```
ionic app is basically a webview. (which I am using)
```

and if this is the reason how can I protect my API key?

I use code to open Google map in android app is

```
showDirection(currentLocation, destLocation) {
    let destination = destLocation.latitude + ',' + destLocation.longitude;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      directionsService.route({
        origin: currentLocation,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function (response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          let mapUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/?';
          var route = response.routes[0];
          route.legs.forEach((value, index) => {
            if (index == 0) {
              mapUrl += 'saddr' + value.start_address + '&daddr=' + value.end_address;
            } else {
              mapUrl += '+to:' + value.end_address;
            }
          });
          window.location.href = mapUrl;
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
  }
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android app restriction is only valid for Google Maps SDK for Android. In your case when you use Ionic with WebView and Google Maps JavaScript API the only supported restriction is HTTP referrer.

You can check yourself which type of restriction is supported by each API on this page

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

In order to set valid HTTP referrer restriction in your Ionic app you should check what value has `window.location.href` when you open a map in your WebView.

For example, if the `window.location.href` is something like `file://some/path` you should use this value as referrer.

Also note that URLs with a file:// protocol require special representation as explained in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key

**Note:** file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the key restriction. The "file://" part should be replaced with "_*file_url*_" before being added to the key restriction. For example, "file:///path/to/" should be formatted as "_*file_url*_//path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.

#### UPDATE

I believe you can avoid using DirectionsService and open Google Maps directly with [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) in directions mode

The code snippet might be

```
showDirection(currentLocation, destLocation) {
    const destination = destLocation.latitude + ',' + destLocation.longitude;
    let mapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1";
    mapUrl += "&origin=" + currentLocation;
    mapUrl += "&destination=" + destination;
    mapUrl += "&travelmode=driving";
    mapUrl += "&dir_action=navigate";
    window.location.href = mapUrl;
}
```

In this scenario you don't need using Google Maps JavaScript API, you don't need an API key and you don't pay for using Maps JavaScript API service.

Comment: As I mentioed in question I dont open google map in webView, I launch google map application from ionic app to show direction to the user using DirectionsService.

Comment: I am getting `http://localhost/#/page` as  window.location.href value...is it safe to use this value as  referrer? @xomena

Comment: I am not getting how the DirectionsService is related to opening a Google Maps app. These things are not related in my opinion. Why don't you use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) in deriections mode in order to launch an intent? In this case you don't need any API key neither DirectionsService, because Google Maps URLs will open native app directly.

Comment: i updated the question...can you please check what I am doing is correct or is there another way to achieve this?